# android SQLiteOpenHelper and Leaks

Tags: android, sqlite, memory-leaks

I wanna make SQLiteOpenHelper with some additional methods (like getStreetsCursor) which returns data from my db. So i wrote something like this:

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper { 
    public static final String DB_NAME="some.db"; 
    public static final String T1_NAME="streets"; 
    public static final String T1_FNAME1="name"; 
    public static final String T2_NAME="addresses"; 
    public static final String T2_FNAME1="name"; 
    public static final String T2_FNAME2="address"; 

    private Context appContext;

  public DBHelper(Context context) { 
    super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);
    appContext=context;
  }

  public Cursor getStreetsCursor(String chars) {
  SQLiteDatabase dbReadable=this.getReadableDatabase();
      Cursor curStreets = dbReadable.query(DBHelper.T1_NAME, 
                new String[] {"_id",DBHelper.T1_FNAME1}, 
                DBHelper.T1_FNAME1+" LIKE(\""+chars.toUpperCase()+"%\")",
                null, null, null, DBHelper.T1_FNAME1);

    return curStreets;
  }
```

There are several methods like getStreetsCursor (getAddresses, getAddress4 etc) defined in DBHelper.
I guess if it is a DB **Helper** it definitely should have such methods i mean the DBHelper is a logical placeholder for them.

What i do in the activity is create a new DBHelper instance and store it in private field (called mDBHelper) of activity. Additionally in onDestroy method of activity i have mDBHelper.close().

```
private DBHelper mDBHelper;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mDBHelper = new DBHelper(this);
...
    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        if (mDBHelper!=null){
            mDBHelper.close();
            Log.i(APP_TAG,"mDBHelper.close() in "+this.getClass());
        }
        super.onDestroy();
    }
```

Those activities uses the mDBHelper only in one way - by calling it's custom methods like mDBHelper.getStreetsCursor(). 
Eventually I found an exception message in logcat about my app got leaks in such activities which uses DBHelper. It says something like "database was never closed". So i decided to add a call to close() method in each of my custom methods just before return. So it looks like:

```
      public Cursor getStreetsCursor(String chars) {
          SQLiteDatabase dbReadable=this.getReadableDatabase();
          Cursor curStreets = dbReadable.query(DBHelper.T1_NAME, 
                    new String[] {"_id",DBHelper.T1_FNAME1}, 
                    DBHelper.T1_FNAME1+" LIKE(\""+chars.toUpperCase()+"%\")",
                    null, null, null, DBHelper.T1_FNAME1);

            dbReadable.close();
            return curStreets;
      }
```

Now i got no leaks but got the next problem - only first call to mDBHelper.getStreetsCursor() really executes. All of the next calls returns null. Thats due to dbReadable.close(); line. If i remove it everythig works fine but i got leaks again.
So i cant figure out whats going wrong. In every custom method i got SQLiteDatabase dbReadable=this.getReadableDatabase(); line which should return a readable instance but after executing the close() method it doesn't.
I guess its about my custom methods because they calls .getReadableDatabase() inside an instance of DBHelper. If i place those methods directly in activity everything works fine - no leak exceptions and every time methods returns a proper data. But i want to place those methods in my DBHelper class.

So the main question is - what's wrong and how to do that properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Years after... I just want to state that now I'll better use Realm.io DB engine and I do it now in my projects. As for my old question I also want to notice that using `getReadableDatabase()` is a bad idea since across devices fragmentation I met some curios sqlite bug - readable instance will be closed automatically right after a query execution which is unexpected behavior. So I recommend always use `getWritableDatabase()` method even for reading purpose. And finally I end up with [Dmytro Danylyk solution - give it a try, Dmytro is Google Developer Expert](http://www.dmytrodanylyk.com/concurrent-database-access/):

```
public class DatabaseManager {

    private AtomicInteger mOpenCounter = new AtomicInteger();

    private static DatabaseManager instance;
    private static SQLiteOpenHelper mDatabaseHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase mDatabase;

    public static synchronized void initializeInstance(SQLiteOpenHelper helper) {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new DatabaseManager();
            mDatabaseHelper = helper;
        }
    }

    public static synchronized DatabaseManager getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(DatabaseManager.class.getSimpleName() +
                    " is not initialized, call initializeInstance(..) method first.");
        }

        return instance;
    }

    public synchronized SQLiteDatabase openDatabase() {
        if(mOpenCounter.incrementAndGet() == 1) {
            // Opening new database
            mDatabase = mDatabaseHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        }
        return mDatabase;
    }

    public synchronized void closeDatabase() {
        if(mOpenCounter.decrementAndGet() == 0) {
            // Closing database
            mDatabase.close();

        }
    }
}
```

And use it as follows.

```
SQLiteDatabase database = DatabaseManager.getInstance().openDatabase();  
database.insert(...);  
// database.close(); Don't close it directly!
DatabaseManager.getInstance().closeDatabase(); // correct way
```

Answer (score 5):

You shouldn't have a `SQLiteDatabase dbReadable=this.getReadableDatabase();`
 in every method `getSomethingCursor` as requesting a database object is expensive ( I think I read it in SO).

So you can create the object from your constructor

```
  SQLiteDatabase dbReadable;

  public DBHelper(Context context) { 
    super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);
    appContext=context;
    dbReadable=this.getReadableDatabase()
  }


  public Cursor getStreetsCursor(String chars) {
          Cursor curStreets = dbReadable.query(DBHelper.T1_NAME, 
                    new String[] {"_id",DBHelper.T1_FNAME1}, 
                    DBHelper.T1_FNAME1+" LIKE(\""+chars.toUpperCase()+"%\")",
                    null, null, null, DBHelper.T1_FNAME1);

            return curStreets;
  }
```

Create a method to close the database handle:

```
public closeDb() {
    if (dbReadable != null) { dbReadable.close();}
}
```

And in you activity:

```
    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        if (mDBHelper!=null){
            mDBHelper.closeDb();
            Log.i(APP_TAG,"mDBHelper.close() in "+this.getClass());
        }
        super.onDestroy();
    }
```

And use [startManagingCursor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startManagingCursor%28android.database.Cursor%29) (if SDK < HoneyComb) to let your activity manage your cursor (closing it on `onDestroy` for example

Comment: Thanx. But what if its the first run, i mean there is no db created  yet. I guess i just cant use dbReadable=this.getReadableDatabase() in the constructor is that case...

Comment: and shouldn't i use the finalize instead of creating closeDb?

Comment: Before you make a call to your method, you have to instantiate your class. So when you instantiate it, you are getting in the same time your `SQLiteDatabase` object.

Comment: in case of database wasn't yet created .getReadable returns null.

Comment: So now i have to check if dbReadable isn't null in every my method. 
but anyway the solution seems to be a good one.
And thanx for startManagingCursor notice.

Comment: From the Android reference, calling getWritableDatabase() is not expensive, as the database is cached. I don't know if it's also the case for getReadableDatabase(): "Once opened successfully, the database is cached, so you can call this method every time you need to write to the database."
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper#getWritableDatabase()

Answer (score 0):

Make `SQLiteDatabase dbReadable` a class member, and implement

```
public void close()
{
    dbReadable.close();
}
```

Then, when you call `mDBHelper.close();` in your activity's `onDestroy()` function, it should be ok.

Answer (score 0):

Make a new function

```
public void DBclose()
{
curstreets.close();
dbReadable.close();
}
```

Then you can call this in your activity in `onDestroy()` fucntion.